# Unable to extend VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010

A quick question on VLOOKUP.

I have two sheets ("Sheet2" acting as source or list of elements and "Sheet1" is where the VLOOKUP formula will be used)

[image]
[image]

I have created a name so that I can reuse the vlookup formula for A2 (Sheet1) also.

[image]

The issue is when I drag the formula to B2 in Sheet1 (where I want the VLOOKUP to be applied) it is showing me error and upon inspection I found that the variable I created "qw" is dynamically changing for every row.

See below :

[image]

QUESTION :

Can someone tell me how to apply VLOOKUP formula to B2 in Sheet1 ?.

Comment: You should use absolute reference in named range definition (`=Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While defining name range you should use the absolute reference for eg. If you want to set the name range to qw then its reference should be like =Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4 which means range get fixed. And if you drag the formula it will refer to same range